# How do I fix an initializer with assigned parameter

Tags: swift

```
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
func even_number(of: [Int]) -> [Int] {

var count = 0


if let numberArray = numberArray {

    for number in numberArray {

    if numberArray % 2 == 0 {
    count += 1
}
return number
```

//Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[Int]'I tried to unwrapped numberArray still get same error pls help!

I'm getting this error please

//Binary operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Int]' and 'Int'.

```
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

func even_number(of: [Int]) -> [Int] {

  var count = 0

for number in numberArray {

    if numberArray % 2 == 0 {
    count += 1
}
return numberArray
}

}
```

Binary operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Int]' and 'Int'

Thanks to everyone that responded to this thread. Below is a a solution using for loop after I got ideas and other way of writing this code I fix the issue with the for loop.

```
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

  func evenNumber(numbers: [Int]) -> [Int] {

  var array: [Int] = []

   for number in numbers {

   if number % 2 == 0 {

  array.append(number)
   }
  }
  return array
 }
 let newArray = evenNumber(numbers: numberArray)

  print(newArray)

Happy Coding!
```

Comment: I answered your question, but when reading it again, I see you might want a different result. Currently you're returning `numberArray`, which isn't altered. What do you want the function to do? Do you want it to return an array with only even numbers?

Comment: Yes I want a new array but only with the even number by the way thanks for your time and answer

Answer (score 3):

From your question I can't figure out what it is *exactly* what you want.

***Return array with the even numbers***

If you want to return the same array, but only the even numbers in there, you could do this:

```
func even_number(of numberArray: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return numberArray.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
}
```

Or:

```
func even_number(of numberArray: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return numberArray.filter { number in
        number % 2 == 0 
    }
}
```

***Return the amount of even numbers in the array***

If you want the *amount* of numbers in the array that are even:

```
func even_number(of numberArray: [Int]) -> Int {
    return numberArray.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }.count
}
```

Or:

```
func even_number(of numberArray: [Int]) -> Int {
    return numberArray.filter { number in
        number % 2 == 0 
    }.count
}
```

***Usage***

You call this function in the following way:

```
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let evenNumbers = even_number(of: numberArray)
```

***Alternative: no function***

You don't *need* to have a function for this, as it's really simple. You could simply do this instead (for getting an array with only even numbers):

```
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let evenNumbers = numberArray.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
```

Or this for getting the amount of even numbers in the given array:

```
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let evenNumbers = numberArray.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }.count
```

***Further explanation of `filter()`***

I find this to give a good explanation of how this works: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer

Comment: No problem, I hope this works! :-) If it doesn't, let me know and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you need to count the number of evens in `numberArray`.

Issue in your code,

**1.** you're returning `[Int]` instead of `Int`.

```
func even_number(of: [Int]) -> [Int]
```

**2.** you're performing `%` operation on `numberArray` instead of `number`

```
if numberArray % 2 == 0 {
```

**Solution:**

There is no need to create a separate method `even_number(of:)`, you can simply get the `count` using **`reduce(_:_:)`** method on `numberArray`,

```
let count = numberArray.reduce(0, { $0 + (($1 % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0) })
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate